# how to include <strong> tag in 18n

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

on my message.json file

```
"step5":{
     "message": "Press Start.<strong>Warning:</strong>
    }
```

it finally shows like this

`Press Start.<strong>Warning:</strong>`

but i want to show it like this Press Start Warning:
(warning should be strong in the front end, what i should do?)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you split your tag into two different tags.

So your current:

```
"step5":{
  "message": "Press Start.<strong>Warning:</strong>"
}
```

Becomes:

```
"step5" : {
  "message": "Press Start.",
  "message_warning": "Warning:",
}
```

This way, your markup is unchanged, and whenever you need to update it, you can reuse the tags you defined before.

Let's assume you're using a template engine such as [Pug](https://pugjs.org/), with this kind of markup:

```
.alert
  p Press Start!
    strong Warning!
```

Over time, you probably will need to change the markup to something like:

```
.new-alert
  p Press Start
(...)
.another-div
  button Warning!
```

Using tag separation, this change will not affect markup as it focuses on the text and not the actual markup.

Comment: your solution is amazing.Do we have a easier way?

Comment: @12345GG There's no point in trying to render markup inside a tag of `i18n`, it also gives you the ability to handle the tags without actually messing with your markup (which can change over time)

Comment: @12345GG I updated my answer with this clarification